# things to consider for qt application development on winXP on atom processor

Tags: iphone, qt, embedded, touchscreen

I am going to develop voip,iptv based application using QT on OS-WinXP and Platform-Atom processor for handheld device

1. As a application programmer point of view if I will not think about the drivers what are the other things I need to consider for this project? Like what should be the software layers in the handheld device?
2. I want to develop the touch screen GUI like Apple iPhone. All the widgets in QT now is window based. Can anybody suggest is there any QT widget gallery for touchscreen GUI like iPhone ?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the GUI elements in your second point, any or all of the Qt examples shown can have how they are drawn change through the use of `QStyle` subclasses.  In addition to that, you can easily make a full-screen window, where no borders or window frames are shown.  If you combine those two options (a full-screen window as background, with styled widgets on it), you can make a GUI that can appear just as nice as the iPhone GUI.  The actual behavior in some widgets may be slightly different, but I'm assuming you know the basics of changing behavior via settings and subclassing.